# Catch attribute change on automatically changed elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create two selections on my webpage which will be connected to each other so that both selections will always be the same. Let me explain in a mock example:

I have a webpage with two selects:

```
<select class="myselector">
    <option value='1'>1
        <br>
    </option>
    <option value='2'>2
        <br>
    </option>
</select>
<select class="myselector">
    <option value='1'>1
        <br>
    </option>
    <option value='2'>2
        <br>
    </option>
</select>
```

*Note*: in reality, I have more than just the two selects and I want them all to be connected.

Now, I want the webpage to automatically set the second selector to the value of the first if the first is changed. I also want to perform some other things on the select that has changed, so I also want the change event to trigger on the other selector. My first thought was simply to do this:

```
function valChange() {
    myfun();
    $('.myselector').val($(this).val());
}
$('.myselector').on('change', valChange);
```

- This does what I need in that it changes the selected values so they match
- This does not trigger the change event in the other select, so `myfun` runs only once

My next thought was to add `$('.myselector').change();` to the end of the `valChange` function, but this (naturally) causes an infinite loop of change events.

My question is, therefore:

> How can I trigger the change event in only the elements that have been
>   changed automatically (not by a user)?

I think it could be done by having both the change and the click event, but that just seems wrong and ugly to me.

---

**EDIT:** I found a way to solve my problem through the use of jquery selectors. If there exists a more elegant way of solving the problem, I will still be happy to see it though.

```
function valChange() {
    myfun()
    var others = $('.myselector[value!=' + $(this).val() + ']');
    others.val($(this).val());
    others.change();
}

$('.myselector').on('change', valChange);
```

JSfiddle for my solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/5xum/svjbdxgs/

Comment: if it has solved your query please mark it as Correct Answer.

Comment: @mulla.azzi It is not what I needed, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use ***each*** method of jquery

```
function valChange() {
     var _this = $(this)
     $('.myselector').each(function(){
          myFun();
          $(this).val(_this.val());
     });
}
$('.myselector').on('change', valChange);
```

here is fiddle for the same [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/psrg6ay6/1/)

Comment: This works, thank you, however I prefer the solution I found as it actually triggers change events for the other selectors.